# Select a specific line if i have the same information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a data as bellow :

```
+--------+----------+-------+------------+--------------+
| month  |   code   |  type   |      date       |    PersonID  |
+--------+----------+-------+------------+--------------+
| 201501 |   178954 |     3 | 2014-12-3  |           10 |
| 201501 |   178954 |     3 | 2014-12-3  |           10 |
| 201501 |   178955 |     2 | 2014-12-13 |           10 |
| 201501 |   178955 |     2 | 2014-12-13 |           10 |
| 201501 |   178956 |     2 | 2014-12-11 |           10 |
| 201501 |   178958 |     1 | 2014-12-10 |           10 |
| 201501 |   178959 |     2 | 2014-12-12 |           15 |
| 201501 |   178959 |     2 | 2014-12-12 |           15 |
| 201501 |   178954 |     1 | 2014-12-11 |           13 |
| 201501 |   178954 |     1 | 2014-12-11 |           13 |
+--------+----------+-------+------------+--------------+
```

In my first 6 lines i have **the same PersonID** in **the same Month** What i want if i have the **same personID** in **the same Month** i want to select the person who have the **type is 2** with **the recent date** in my case the output will be like as bellow:

```
+--------+--------+------+------------+----------+
| month   |  code    | type|    date       | PersonID |
+--------+--------+------+------------+----------+
| 201501 | 178955 |    2 | 2014-12-13 |       10 |
| 201501 | 178959 |    2 | 2014-12-12 |       15 |
| 201501 | 178954 |    2 | 2014-12-11 |       13 |
+--------+--------+------+------------+----------+
```

Also  if they are some duplicate rows i don't want to display it

They are any solution to that ?

Comment: Is something wrong with the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use GROUP BY:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx

```
SELECT mont, code, ... FROM tabelname GROUP BY PersonID, date, ...
```

Note that you have to specifiy all columns in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.month, A.code, A.type, B.date, B.PersonID FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT PersonID, MAX(date) as date FROM YourTable
GROUP BY PersonID) B
ON (A.PersonID = B.PersonID
AND A.date = B.date)
WHERE A.type = 2 ORDER BY B.date DESC, A.PersonID
```

Just in case you/others are still wondering.